# Why does Linux allow a new connection in TIME-WAIT state even when tcp_tw_reuse is disabled?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Why does my linux system accept a SYN for a connection in the TIME-WAIT state?

First I setup a server `sock -s 127.0.0.1 1024` to listen on port 1024
Then I connect to it from port 1025 `sock 127.0.0.1 1024 -b1025 -A`, the -A option enables SO_REUSEADDR
Then I do an active close from the client, now netstat shows this:

```
TIME-WAIT     0          0                  127.0.0.1:1025                  127.0.0.1:1024
```

`sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` returns 0,
So if I then run `sock 127.0.0.1 1024 -b1025 -A` again, it should allow bind(), but not the connect() since tcp_tw_reuse is 0. But it still connects, why?

Comment: What do you see in `netstat` after the second connection? Did it somehow convert the connection from `TIME-WAIT` to `ESTABLISHED`?

Comment: yes, first its ESTABLISHED then i do the active close and its TIME-WAIT, then i connect again and it just switches to ESTABLISHED again

Comment: What is `sock`, is it like `netcat`? Got a link to the documentation? Googling "linux man sock" didn't find it.

Comment: it doesnt matter, it happens even if i run the server with netcat `nc -l 192.168.1.3 1024` and then on the client run python code: 
`sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)`
`sock.bind(("192.168.1.2", 1025))`
`sock.connect(("192.168.1.3", 1024)`

Comment: This is the first I've seen using `SO_REUSEADDR` on the client, it's normally used on the server.

Comment: @Barmar When is it used on the server? Isnt SO_REUSEADDR only useful for the one that does the active close, and usually the client does the active close. When does the server do an active close?

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR is usually used on a server so you can stop the server and restart it while there are old connections using the local port. It's unusual for clients to specify a particular local port, they usually let the system pick an unused port.